# Flutter RawKeyboardListener triggering system sounds on MacOS

Tags: macos, flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

I have a MacOS desktop application built with flutter.
In it I have a RawKeyboardListener widget. it is functioning as expected. It is capturing keyboard input which I could process as normal.

However whenever I press a key the OS level key input rejection sound plays.
That sound that comes up when you press a key in a place where the key specifically won't work.

I haven't encountered this otherwise when using the listener so I'm not even sure where to begin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid beeping for keys you should use the `FocusNode`'s `onKey`, to actually handle the event (i.e., return true), rather than just listening for the existence of the event (like in `RawKeyboardListener`)

Handling the key with the `FocusNode.onKey` is easiest when done with a `Focus` widget:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Focus(
    onKey: (FocusNode node, RawKeyEvent event) => true,
    child: ...
  );
}
```

That will manage the focus node for you (inserting and removing it as necessary).

Comment: `RawKeyboardListener` widget generally listens for input to `w-a-s-d` keys

Comment: Wow. Didn’t know about focusNode on key I’ll switch now and tell you how it goes

Comment: @xerotolerant yes do let me know how it goes

Comment: @xerotolerant Amazing ! Btw not able to reach your website `raiora.com`

Comment: No worries. That company is no longer operating. Will update my bio

Comment: @xerotolerant can you rephrase your question to "RawKeyboardListener key input triggering system sounds on MacOS "

Comment: Lol I had no idea what to call that noise lol. Renamed

Comment: Confirmed still a correct answer in Sept '23